# x. Equals(null) returns false (for non-nullable value types only)

Tags: c#, equality, msdn

While reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms173147(v=vs.90)) I see that Object.Equals override should return false if called for null argument for non-nullable values only:

[image]

At the same time I read the given example - TwoDPoint - is a nullable type, but it contradicts the guideline itself.

[image]

So, what is the best practice for overloading Equals method for a nullable type indeed?

Comment: There's nothing saying that `object.Equals(null)` should not return false for nullable types, it's merely suggesting that such an outcome is not guaranteed (i.e. cannot be relied upon, even though ideally one would generally expect that to be the case).   The example is correct and preferred for nullable types however.  The guarantee is correct for non-nullable value types - there's no contradiction, just different cases.

Comment: [don't put code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TwoDPoint` is a `class` type which is a reference type. As such, the special value `null` is allowed for the reference. So values `p` of type `TwoDPoint` may be `null`.

With a `class` type, where you are inside the `public bool Equals` non-static method, "`this`" is never `null`, and therefore it is correct to return `false` whenever the `p` argument is `null`.

```
// Example 1
var t = new Point(10, 4);
var p = (Point)null;
var isEqual = t.Eqauls(p); // should return 'false', therefore the code you ask about

// Example 2
var t = (Point)null;
var p = (Point)null;
var isEqual = t.Eqauls(p); // 'NullReferenceException', method not called
```

Above, you see how it works for reference types.

With the special `Nullable<>` type which is used for **nullable *value* types**, things are a bit different. But the good news you will not have to write the code for `Nullable<>.Equals` since it is already in the .NET Framework.

```
// Example 3
var t = (TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.FromHours(3.5);
var p = (TimeSpan?)null;
var isEqual = t.Equals(p); // will return 'false'

// Example 4
var t = (TimeSpan?)null;
var p = (TimeSpan?)null;
var isEqual = t.Equals(p); // OK, method will return 'true'!
```

In example 4, no null *reference* occurs. The "null" present is a value of the `Nullable<TimeSpan>` struct which has its `HasValue` property equal to `false`. The `Equals` method is declared (as an override, in this case) in `Nullable<>`, and therefore no boxing occurs.

Different:

```
// Example 5
var t = (TimeSpan?)null;
var type = t.GetType(); // 'GetType' declared in class (System.Object), boxing, 'NullReferenceException'!
```

Answer (score 1):

> TwoDPoint - is a nullable type

No, `TwoDPoint` isn't a nullable type, a [Nullable Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index) should contain a question mark:

`TwoDPoint?` is a nullable type, it is shorthand for `Nullable<TwoDPoint>`

So if you call `Equals` on a nullable type, it won't call the overrided / overloaded method.

```
TwoDPoint? a = new TwoDPoint();
var b = (TwoDPoint)a;

// call Nullable<TwoDPoint>.Equals, not TwoDPoint.Equals
a.Equals(b);

// call TwoDPoint.Equals
b.Equals(b);
```